# How to display data from database to another form by calling it from another form

Tags: c#, mysql

I have created a form in C# for the user to login and when they successfully login, the data of the user who had logged in will be displayed to another form in a gridview. The problem here is when the user successfully logged in then goes to the other form the data was not displayed and i get an error "object reference not set to an instance of an object".

here is my code:
LoginFaculty.cs

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.ComponentModel;
 using System.Data;
 using System.Drawing;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Windows.Forms;
 using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
namespace ClassScheduling
{
public partial class LogInFaculty : Form
{
    public LogInFaculty()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnSignInFaculty_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string myConnection = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=root";
            MySqlConnection myConn = new MySqlConnection(myConnection);
            MySqlCommand SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand(" select * from database.faculty where FullName='" + this.txtBoxUserNameFaculty.Text + "' and Password= '" + this.txtBoxPasswordFaculty.Text + "'", myConn);
            MySqlDataReader myReader;
            myConn.Open();
            myReader = SelectCommand.ExecuteReader();
            string lastname = myReader.ToString();

            int count = 0;
            while (myReader.Read())
            {
                count = count + 1;
            }
            if (count == 1)
            {

                MessageBox.Show("LogIn Sucessfully");
                this.Hide();

                FacultyLoadForm newForm = new FacultyLoadForm();
                newForm.Show();
            }
            else if (count > 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Duplicate Username and password ....Access Denied!");
            }
            else
                MessageBox.Show("Username or Password is incorrect");

            myConn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private void btnExitFaculty_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Account newForm = new Account();
        newForm.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }
}
}
```

then for my FacultyLoad.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace ClassScheduling
{
public partial class LogInFaculty : Form
{
    public LogInFaculty()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnSignInFaculty_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string myConnection = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=root";
            MySqlConnection myConn = new MySqlConnection(myConnection);
            MySqlCommand SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand(" select * from database.faculty where FullName='" + this.txtBoxUserNameFaculty.Text + "' and Password= '" + this.txtBoxPasswordFaculty.Text + "'", myConn);
            MySqlDataReader myReader;
            myConn.Open();
            myReader = SelectCommand.ExecuteReader();
            string lastname = myReader.ToString();

            int count = 0;
            while (myReader.Read())
            {
                count = count + 1;
            }
            if (count == 1)
            {

                MessageBox.Show("LogIn Sucessfully");
                this.Hide();

                FacultyLoadForm newForm = new FacultyLoadForm();
                newForm.Show();
            }
            else if (count > 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Duplicate Username and password ....Access Denied!");
            }
            else
                MessageBox.Show("Username or Password is incorrect");

            myConn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private void btnExitFaculty_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Account newForm = new Account();
        newForm.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }
}
}
```

That's it! I really have no idea why I keep getting that error and I've tried every possible solution I know. If anyone know, please do tell me.

Comment: what line you have error occured...

Comment: your both forms have same code.?? or you have posted the question wrongly..

Comment: I found two the code of two form is similar....Please clearly mentioned the Code

Comment: you mentioned same code twice with two different form names, please check once and update clearly,

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this..

**Code for LoginFaculty.cs:**

```
 private void btnSignInFaculty_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            ...
            ....
            while (myReader.Read())
            {
                count = count + 1;
            }
            if (count == 1)
            {

                MessageBox.Show("LogIn Sucessfully");
                this.Hide();
               //Use Overloaded Constructor..
                FacultyLoadForm newForm = new FacultyLoadForm(this.txtBoxUserNameFaculty.Text , this.txtBoxPasswordFaculty.Text);
                newForm.Show();
            }
            ...
            ...            
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

**Code for FacultyLoad.cs**

```
 // Global Variables, which will be used for Page Load Event to get data...
 string LoginUserName,LoginUserPassword;
 // Over Loaded Constructor..
 public LogInFaculty(string UserName,string Password)
 {
      LoginUserName=UserName;
      LoginUserPassword=Password;
      InitializeComponent();
 }
```

and now in `FacultyLoad.cs Pages Load Event` write your code for filling `Grid View`.

Answer (score 0):

create a constructor for `FacultyLoadForm` and pass all the required values from login form after successful login.

Answer (score 0):

U got the error because u did not pass the user ID to the detail form Properly. there are many  ways to do it. but more acceptable way is save the user ID into a static field of a static class after successful Login. so that you can use that user ID from from any form with out sending the User ID again and again. Please follow the following steps.

1. Create a Static Class name Global.cs at your project. and add a static member named UserID

   ```
   public static class Global
   {
     public static string UserID;
   }
   ```
2. then at your log in form do the following in your log in button click event

   ```
   // if log in successful then
   Global.UserID= txtUserID.Text;
   // call the details form
   // hide the login form
   ```
3. In detail form you can retrieve the UserID in the Following Way

   ```
   string userID=Global.UesrID;
   // now you can user this ID to retrive the detail value of that User
   ```